# Checkbox items to be added on Array with functional components on form

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

I need to add checkbox checked items to respective array, as I am new into React so just need guidance about it.

This is my Array

```
items:[
     {
          id: 3,
          name: "Leanne Graham",
          email: "Sincere@april.biz",
          link: "www.abc.com",
          gender:"Female",
          hobbies:"playing_games",
        },
.
.
]
```

[image: This is my Checkbox on form with bootstrap]

This is my Checkbox on form.

Suppose If I check playing games it should add to that respective array. So how can I do it with hooks, Do I need to pass object initially on items like this or something else.

```
items:[
     {
          id: 3,
          name: "Leanne Graham",
          email: "Sincere@april.biz",
          link: "www.abc.com",
          gender:"Female",
          hobbies:"playing_games:true",
        },
.
.
]
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55968928/9465933), but if you can please let me know how can I do it then I will appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You need to share wider code sample in order for us to suggest meaningful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to get the `checkboxItems`; When a use clicks submit or whatever other action then you have a list of checkboxes in `checkboxItems` and which contains info about which items are checked and which aren't.

```js
const CheckboxForm = () => {
    // Put whatever checkboxes you want in here or pass in as props if that's better
    const initialCheckboxes = [{ name: "test", checked: false}];
    const [checkboxItems, setCheckboxItems] = useState(initialCheckboxes);

    return (
      <div>
        {       
          checkboxItems.map((checkbox, index) => 
            <div>
              <p>{checkbox.name}</p>
              <input
                type={"checkbox"}
                onChange={e => {
                  const newCheckboxes = [...checkboxItems];
                  newCheckboxes[index].checked = e.target.checked;
                  setCheckboxItems(newCheckboxes);
                }}
                checked={checkbox.checked}
              />
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  };
```

If you only want checked items then you can filter them out like this:

```
const checkedItems = checkboxItems.filter(({ checked }) => checked);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried your code. I can able to fetch the checked items, but the prob is once I checked one field like test, I am unable to uncheck ? This is how I defined other two fields initially  


  const initialCheckboxes = [{ name: "test", checked: false,
   },{name: "love", checked: false}];

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the answer to use e.target - Try now.

Comment: U champ. ya thanks it works.My other question is that I am getting an array of checkbox selected items through filter method, outside onChange. now I need to add that to setHobbies hooks. how can I do that ?

Comment: If you accept this as the accepted answer then  open a new question and ask there - Then I can answer better with code.

Comment: sure I will certainly accept it, as its in continuing of the thing, thats why I didn't raise  new question.Can u please tell me here or I will create new one.

Comment: Create a new question so that it's easier for other people who have the same issue as you to see.

Comment: This is the link for new question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409751/checkbox-values-to-be-added-to-state-hooks

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is advice on how to maintain the hobbies within a user profile? This is completely subjective to how you are or want to store your information in your database. It falls in to the category of "there's more than one way to skin a cat".

Given the object you presented, I would probably do it like this:

```js
items:[
   {
      id: 3,
      name: "Leanne Graham",
      email: "Sincere@april.biz",
      link: "www.abc.com",
      gender:"Female",
      hobbies: [
         {playing_games: true},
         {watching_tv: false},
      ],
    },
]
```

This way, you could iterate over the hobbies and populate the checkboxes very easily.