# Checkbox Values to be added to state Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I want to add checkbox checked items to the hooks state. here is the scenerio

This is my initial array

```js
     items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Ramesh Mehta",
          email: "ramesh@gmail.com",
          link: "www.abc.com",
          gender:"Male",
          hobbies:["playing games"],
        },

    ..
    ..
    ]
```

and on AddItem component I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391577/9465933) code.

This is my usestate variable and code to find checked items list array outside onChange of checkbox.

```js
    const [hobbies, setHobbies] = useState([]);
    const [checkboxItems, setCheckboxItems] = useState(initialCheckboxes);

    const checkedItems = checkboxItems.filter(({ checked }) => checked);
    console.log("checkedItems ", checkedItems);
    let myJSON = JSON.stringify(checkedItems);

    var names = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    let result = names.map(a => a.name);

    console.log("checkedItems in String  ",result);//outputs  ["Watching TV", "Playing Games"]
```

now I want to add result into setHobbies hook. I can also change the initial hooks structure if required.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: So you want hobbies to contain all checkedItems?

Comment: Yeah !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use setHobbies to add the result to the hobbies

```
setHobbies(result);
```

Comment: where? I have written anywhere before return. it gives me this error 

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: https://medium.com/@saswatamcode/getting-hooked-on-react-hooks-b7a5d3f23bf According to this site we have to write setState method inside return method under some events. is it true ?